# How to print a python print() to linux terminal out of a systemd service?

Tags: python, linux, systemd

With this code i try to print things to the linux console of my raspberry pi

```
print("test1")
sys.stdout.write("test2")
sys.stdout.flush()
```

This works if i run the python program out of a systemd service.

If i put the python program into a shell script and let the systemd service execute the shell script, then i can't see the print()s anymore.

```
[Unit]
Description=Kodi Service
After=network-online.target
Wants=network-online.target

[Service]
Type=forking
User=root
WorkingDirectory=/root/kodi/
ExecStart=/bin/bash /root/kodi/run_python.sh
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The run_python.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash    
python3 /root/kodi/validator.py
```

Comment: systemd wouldn't know or connect to whatever terminal session you're running. You would have to write to file, then read (cat/tail -f) that file to see the result.

Comment: Just to explain a bit more... if you think about it, Linux is multi-user, so how would systemd know which user's Terminal you wanted to write on? And it's multi-session, so how would it know which screen/ssh-session you wanted the output written to? And you can have multiple Terminal windows in a login session, so how would it know which Terminal?

Comment: So just running the python programm without a systemd service should print the outputs directly on the terminal? I do not need the systemd service, but i thought it's better to just put the python programm to rc.local ... but this seems to be the easier solution

Comment: @MarkSetchell thanks for further explanation, but i want to just write it to the "local" terminal of my raspberry pi where i have a monitor connected via hdmi

Comment: You'd use systemd or similar systems, if you want the program to run without anyone being logged in. E.g., every half hour, every two days, continuously; doesn't matter. That is what system processes are for: run without user input.

Comment: If you just want to run a Python script and observe its output, there is absolutely no need to use systemd. It would just complicate things for you.

Comment: Is rc.local still be the right way for running a python program after startup or is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: That really depends on what you want to achieve. If there really is something that *should* be done on boot, and can't really be done manually after logging on by a user, then rc.local might be something you can use. But your given example script is far, far from that, and doesn't fit rc.local use.

Comment: It's unclear to me why you ask about rc.local and running a program at boot, when your question is about systemd and terminal output. These are somewhat different things.

Comment: Want i want to achieve is running this python script after boot but without the need of an user logging in. If you say i am far away from rc.local, what would you recommend?

Comment: Just try it as the last line in `rc.local` and see if it works as you want - it should only take 3 minutes including booting. You'll likely want `&` at the end of the line.